# Shiny Checkbox Button Width & Centered

Tags: r, shiny, shinydashboard

I created a UI page with some buttons and have two problems with the checkboxInput buttons:

```
  checkboxInput('comissions', label = "Comissions", width = "10%")
```

Changing the width = "X%" doesn't change anything, same for 'Xpx'.
I suspected this is due to fixed column width, but the X% change works for other buttons well.

Second issue is that the button looks like this:

[image]

I would like it to be centered and not be in left column.

Thank you for the help,

Comment: Try changing the width and centering specification of the parent container element?  Centering would happen relative to the parent (which would specify if its child elements are centered or left-justified)

Comment: What do you expect to get by changing the width ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here is a way to center the checkbox, but it requires `width = "100%"`.

```
library(shiny)

ui <- basicPage(
  fluidRow(
    column(4, 
           sliderInput("costs", "Costs", min = 1, max = 10,  value = 1)),
    column(4, style = "text-align: center;", 
           checkboxInput("comissions", label = "Comissions", width = "100%")),
    column(4, 
           sliderInput("periods", "Number of periods", min = 1, max = 10,  value = 1))
  )
)

server <- function(input, output, session) {}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

[image]

I don't know what you expect to see by changing the width ?

---

## EDIT

To control the white space around the checkbox input, and its vertical alignment:

```
library(shiny)

ui <- basicPage(
  fluidRow(
    column(12,
           div(style = "display: inline-block;", 
               sliderInput("costs", "Costs", min = 1, max = 10,  value = 1)
           ),
           div(style = "display: inline-block; margin-left: 20px; margin-right: 20px; vertical-align: -20px;", 
               checkboxInput("comissions", label = "Comissions", width = "100%")
           ),
           div(style = "display: inline-block;", 
               sliderInput("periods", "Number of periods", min = 1, max = 10,  value = 1)
           )
    )
  )
)

server <- function(input, output, session) {}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

[image]

Comment: Thats very helpful. What about vertical alignment? So it is in the middle.

I want to make the button small so it doesn't take all this extra empty space. But I believe this is limited by the size of my columns?

Comment: @Arkadiw To change the vertical position, you can add `div(style = "margin-top : 40px;"),` just before `checkboxInput`. I will try to get rid of the empty space, see you later.

Comment: great answer, 4 years after it was published. @StéphaneLaurent you should write a manual!